# Adobe Flash Player being glitchy

Tags: flash, adobe

This problem has only been happening for the last week. Whenever I watch a video (online) thats run with Flash Player, or play a Flash game, it's really glitchy. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adobe announced that They will no longer provide new releases of Flash Player for Linux after version 11.2.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/adobe-adandons-flash-on-linux/)

This might be Flash Player bug, Re watch that video again in last version of [Google Chrome Browser](http://www.google.com/chrome) or update your flash player (if available).

Comment: I did try in Chrome. The same issue occurs. Do you think a different Flash Player (Like Gnash) would work?

Comment: I have not use them yet, but as far as i know "Gnash" is good for viewing "YouTube" video.